# Selection attribute value with xpath by filtering on a subitem-value

Tags: xpath

how can I select a node-attribute with **xpath** by filtering on a subnode-attribute?

I have a xml structure like this:

```
<base>
  <item name="foo">
    <subitem value="blubb" />
  </item>
</base>
```

Now I want the name-attribute-value ("foo") from the item-tag(s) where the value-attribute of the subitem(s) is "blubb".

Thx 4 help

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

**`string(/*/item[subitem/@value='blubb']/@name)`**